# MvcMailer: Taking user input in view through model and then inserting it into mail

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, model, mvcmailer

I don't know if I am explaining this correctly, or if the solution is rather simple, so here goes:

I am using MvcMailer, but before that I set up a wizard input form which I call Quote.cshtml. Behind Quote.cshtml, I set up a model called QuoteModel.cs.

Quote.cshtml at its most basic (I am leaving out all of the wizard logic and only showing one input):

```
<td width="40%">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "mylabelstyle", title = "Enter first name." })
</td>
<td width="60%">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FirstName)
</td>
```

QuoteModel.cs (again, only showing the one input; n.b.: using the [DataAnnotationExtensions](http://dataannotationsextensions.org/))

```
public class QuoteModel
{ 
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "First Name required.")]
    [Display(Name = "First Name:")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

Now I am trying to integrate MvcMailer, which sets up IQuoteMailer.cs, QuoteMailer.cs, _Layout.cshtml, and QuoteMail.cshtml.  The QuoteMail.cshtml is what the recipient of the mail will eventually see. I also set up a QuoteController.cs, in which I placed the appropriate code required by MvcMailer. It is in the QuoteMailer.cs and QuoteController.cs where I am having trouble passing the user input from Quote.cshtml (which is based on the model in QuoteModel.cs).

IQuoteMailer.cs:

```
 public interface IQuoteMailer
    {               
         MailMessage QuoteMail();
    }
```

QuoteMailer.cs:

```
public class QuoteMailer : MailerBase, IQuoteMailer     
{
    public QuoteMailer():
        base()
    {
        MasterName="_Layout";
    }


    public virtual MailMessage QuoteMail()
    {
        var mailMessage = new MailMessage{Subject = "QuoteMail"};

        mailMessage.To.Add("some-email@example.com");
        ViewBag.Data = someObject; 
                    //I imagine this is where I can pass my model, 
                    //but I am not sure (do I have to iterate each and
                    //every input (there are like 20 in QuoteModel.cs)?

                return mailMessage;
    }
```

QuoteMail.cshtml (_Layout.cshtml is pretty standard, so not showing here):

```
@*HTML View for QuoteMailer#QuoteMail*@

Welcome to MvcMailer and enjoy your time!<br />
<div class="mailer_entry">
    <div class="mailer_entry_box">
        <div class="mailer_entry_text">
            <h2>
                INSERT_TITLE
            </h2>
            <p>
                INSERT_CONTENT
                //I believe I am going to use a "@" command like @ViewData
                //to pass FirstName, but again, not sure how to bind 
                //the model and then pass it.
            </p>
            <p>
                INSERT_CONTENT
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And finally, the relevant parts of the QuoteController.cs (note that I have am using a wizard, therefore, part of my problem is figuring out where to put the MvcMailer code, but I think I may have it right):

public class QuoteController: Controller
    {

```
    /// <summary>
    /// MvcMailer
    /// </summary>
    private IQuoteMailer _quoteMailer = new QuoteMailer();
    public IQuoteMailer QuoteMailer
    {
        get { return _quoteMailer; }
        set { _quoteMailer = value; }
    }

    //
    // GET: /Quote/
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Quote()
    {
        HtmlHelper.ClientValidationEnabled = true;
        HtmlHelper.UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled = true;
        //In order to get the clientside validation (unobtrusive), 
        //the above lines are necessary (where action takes place)
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Matrimonial/
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Quote(QuoteModel FinishedQuote)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            QuoteMailer.QuoteMail().Send();
            return View("QuoteMailSuccess", FinishedQuote);
        }
        else return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Matrimonial/Confirm
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult QuoteMailConfirm(QuoteModel FinishedQuote)
    {
        return PartialView(FinishedQuote);
    }
```

}

So, my confusion is to how to pass the QuoteModel I created, so that ultimately I can take the user inputed data and then generate the MvcMailer view.

I appreciate the communities help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could have the `IQuoteMailer` interface take the model:

```
public interface IQuoteMailer
{
    MailMessage QuoteMail(QuoteModel model);
}
```

and in the implementation use this model:

```
public class QuoteMailer : MailerBase, IQuoteMailer
{
    public QuoteMailer() : base()
    {
        MasterName = "_Layout";
    }


    public virtual MailMessage QuoteMail(QuoteModel model)
    {
        var mailMessage = new MailMessage
        {
            Subject = "QuoteMail"
        };
        mailMessage.To.Add("some-email@example.com");

        // Use a strongly typed model
        ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(model);
        PopulateBody(mailMessage, "QuoteMail", null);
        return mailMessage;
    }
}
```

then from the controller when you decide to send the mail pass the model:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Quote(QuoteModel FinishedQuote)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        QuoteMailer.QuoteMail(FinishedQuote).Send();
        return View("QuoteMailSuccess", FinishedQuote);
    }
    else return View();
}
```

and finally in the template (`~/Views/QuoteMailer/QuoteMail.cshtml`) you could use the model:

```
@using AppName.Models
@model QuoteModel

Welcome to MvcMailer and enjoy your time!
<br />
<div class="mailer_entry">
    <div class="mailer_entry_box">
        <div class="mailer_entry_text">
            <h2>
                INSERT_TITLE
            </h2>
            <p>
                Hello @Model.FirstName
            </p>
            <p>
                INSERT_CONTENT
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Out and about.  Thanks for answering. Will check later and report progress.

Comment: This worked great, but I was really expecting the PopulateBody function to have a Model parameter.  I guess I can add an extension method easily enough.

Comment: @BenMills The model appears to be passed through the IQuoteMailer interface `QuoteMail()`, through the Post in the Controller.

Comment: `QuoteMailer.QuoteMail(FinishedQuote).Send();` -> `cannot access internal method 'Send' here`